# .mouseenter() doesn't work on content loaded with jQuerys .load() function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, hover, fadein

I have a page, with a navigationbar that loads content, from another page, into a content-div, when a navigation item is clicked.

The content from the other page contains a variety of different divs. One of these divs has the style `display: none`. This div is on top of another div. When I .mouseenter() on the div that is below the hidden div, I need the hidden div to .fadeIn().

.load() jQuery as follows:

```
var workitem;
// When the navigationitem is clicked
$("ul.worklist li", this).click(function() {

// Get the id-attribute, to decide what div to load          
      workitem = $(this).attr("id");

// Declare a variable that describes the contents location
      var getitem = "work.aspx #" + workitem;
// Load the content with the .load function, and add some cool fadeIn effects
      $("#workcontent").load(getitem, function() {
            $(".webImg:hidden").delay(1000).fadeIn(200, function() {
                $(".logoImg:hidden").fadeIn(200, function() {
                    $(".printImg:hidden").fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $(".projBeskrivelse:hidden").fadeIn(800);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
// Do stuff to the navigation panel
        $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#000' }, 100);
        $(this).siblings("li").animate({ 'line-height': '24px', color: '#ddd' }, 300);
    });
```

The div #workitem contains the following elements

```
<div class="webImg">
    <div class="webImgOverlay"><p>Go to website ►</p></div> <!-- This is the element that has the display: hidden attribute in it's class -->
    <img src="work/xxxxx_web_550_451.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="logoImg">
    <img src="work/let_logo_199_325.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="printImg">
    <img src="work/xxxxx_print_199_101.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="projBeskrivelse">
        <p class='header'>xxxxx</p>
        <p class='brodtekst'>This project is developed for the danish waiter rental company, xxxxx. The assigment included a redesign of their logo, their website and a general makeover of the visual identity. The project was made because xxxxx was expanding with a catering subdivision.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Now when I .mouseenter() on the .webImg div, I want the following to happen:

```
$(".workitem", this).mouseenter(function() {
    $(".webImgOverlay").fadeIn(200);
});
$(".workitem", this).mouseleave(function() {
    $(".webImgOverlay").fadeOut(200);
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is this because the content is loaded with ajax? Is there any way to accomplish this with jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for elements dynamically added to `#workcontent`, like this:

```
$("#workcontent").delegate('.workitem', 'mouseenter', function() {
    $(".webImgOverlay").fadeIn(200);
}).delegate('.workitem', 'mouseleave', function() {
    $(".webImgOverlay").fadeOut(200);
});
```

In other cases, the more general [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) works:

```
$(".workitem").live('mouseenter', function() {
    $(".webImgOverlay").fadeIn(200);
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
    $(".webImgOverlay").fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: @Mads, just to clarify on the *why*: The events were attached to *existing* elements within the dom. Any elements added later will not have events attached unless explicitly attached later. With `delegate` the event *delegate* captures the event and looks for any child elements that match the selector when the event is fired. `live` is essentially the same thing with the document as the delegate.